Drag and drop and reorder plotly barchart
How to enable re-ordering plotly bar chart by drag and drop the chart bars.
<plotly-plot
[divId]="graph.selectedGraph.name"
[data]="graph.selectedGraph.data"
[config]="graph.selectedGraph.config"
[layout]="layout"
(relayout)="draggedShape($event)"
[ngClass]="{ 'single-data': graph.data && graph.data.length === 1 }"
(click)="launchColorPicker($event)">
</plotly-plot>

